# How to pass a variable to the dataset for a graph in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I'm trying to create a graph in chart.js partly using data values that are static and given in the code, but also partly using data values given by the user. The value of the variable is subject to change because it is a sum of different parsed inputs from the user, and I'd like the chart to be able to update in real-time based on changes in the sum.

I understand that the below code returns an error because the variable `classaverage` is not defined, and also understand that it is possible to just repeat the calling of the class names and do the calculations all over again underneath the `Chart()` function. But, as the actual table is actually much larger than the one in the sample, I'd prefer to use a shorter method and not have to take up all of that space. Is this possible?

My code:

```js
document.getElementById("jack").contentEditable = true;
document.getElementById("john").contentEditable = true;
document.getElementById("joe").contentEditable = true;

function myFunction() {
  var jack2 = document.getElementById("jack").innerText;
  var john2 = document.getElementById("john").innerText;
  var joe2 = document.getElementById("joe").innerText;

  var total2 = (parseInt(jack2) || 0) + (parseInt(john2) || 0) + (parseInt(joe2) || 0);

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total2;
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('totalchart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',

  data: {
    labels: ['Class', 'City', 'District'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Average Weight',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      data: [classaverage, 130, 135]
    }]
  },

  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 200,
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table,
tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-style: Arial;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="cell">
    <th>Person</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td id="jack" oninput="myFunction()">120</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>John</td>
    <td id="john" oninput="myFunction()">140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Joe</td>
    <td id="joe" oninput="myFunction()">150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cell">
    <td>Total</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<canvas id="totalchart"></canvas>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve with your calculations if you update your answer I will be able to show you a working example, but to update the chart in real-time you will need to addData():

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

and possibly removeData():

```
function removeData(chart) {
    chart.data.labels.pop();
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.pop();
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

unless you replaceData():

```
function replaceData(chart, data) {
    chart.data.labels = Object.keys(data);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data = Object.values(data);
    });
    chart.update();
}
```

I have created an example [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9zjx4co/2/) showing implementation of addData

please refer to the [docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)